# Javascript regex to remove all punctuation except "." and "?"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been using a regex replace to remove all punctuation from a text box value and replace the whitespaces left by the removal. It is working great except I have realized I need it to leave `.` and `?` in the field. Here is what I am currently using. How can I skip those two characters but remove all others?

script

```
var special = special.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `[^\w\s?.]` for your character class.

Comment: @user1881482: You can also remove the second replace (for duplicate spaces) using: `special.replace(/(?:[^\w?.]+|_+)+/g, " ")` or more efficient: `special.replace(/(?:[^\w?.]+_*|_+)+/g, " ")`

Comment: @Bergi: You can't have a catastrophic backtracking here since there is nothing after the non-capturing group. So even if you have quantifiers in a repeated group, since nothing can fail after, there is no reason that a backtracking happens once the position after the quantifier of the group is reached.

Comment: Note that the precedent pattern can be improved using the first character discrimination (to avoid to test the alternation for each character of the string): `special.replace(/(?=[\W_])(?:[^\w?.]+_*|_+)+/g, " ")` see : https://regex101.com/r/tD7wB0/2

Comment: OK, it might not happen, but `([…]+_*|_+)+` looks terrible